# TOC shows up everywhere in a beamer template

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I'm using a template for my presentation and I want the table of contents to show in the frame defined for it below, and nowhere else. But it keeps showing at the start of every section and i do not understand which part of the template's code does this.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
% \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ctex, hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% other packages
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,xcolor,multicol,booktabs,calligra}
\usepackage{graphicx,pstricks,listings,stackengine}

\usepackage{wrapfig,tikz}

\author{My name}
\title{My title}
\institute{My school}
\date{the date}
\usepackage{whu}

% defs
\def\cmd#1{\texttt{\color{red}\footnotesize $\backslash$#1}}
\def\env#1{\texttt{\color{blue}\footnotesize #1}}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{deepblue},
    emphstyle=\ttfamily\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
    stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\small\color{halfgray},
    rulesepcolor=\color{red!20!green!20!blue!20},
    frame=shadowbox,
}

\begin{document}

\kaishu
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
    \begin{figure}[htpb]
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth]{pic/whulogo.jpeg}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,subsubsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide]
\end{frame}

% \section{thing}
% [...]
\end{document}
```

It seems other people's questions about it on StackExchange are more interested in showing the toc everywhere except at the start of a specific section. How do i get it to go away everywhere except it's dedicated frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this is the `whu` theme you are using https://github.com/Xinchen-Fan/WHU-Beamer-Theme/blob/master/whu.sty then you can suppress the toc at the start of new sections with `\AtBeginSection{}`

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
% \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{ctex, hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% other packages
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,xcolor,multicol,booktabs,calligra}
\usepackage{graphicx,pstricks,listings,stackengine}

\usepackage{wrapfig,tikz}

\author{My name}
\title{My title}
\institute{My school}
\date{the date}
\usepackage{whu}

% defs
\def\cmd#1{\texttt{\color{red}\footnotesize $\backslash$#1}}
\def\env#1{\texttt{\color{blue}\footnotesize #1}}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{deepblue},
    emphstyle=\ttfamily\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
    stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\small\color{halfgray},
    rulesepcolor=\color{red!20!green!20!blue!20},
    frame=shadowbox,
}

\AtBeginSection{}

\begin{document}

%\kaishu
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
    \begin{figure}[htpb]
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,subsubsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide]
\end{frame}

 \section{thing}
 
 \begin{frame}
 content...
 \end{frame}
% [...]
\end{document}
```